# Как в одном .htaccess файла запретить доступ сразу к нескольким папкам?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер, доступ

Как запретить доступ к папке на сайте я знаю: просто создать в ней файл .htaccess с таким вот содержимым:

```
deny from all
```

А если в папку которую мы хотим защитить нельзя класть какие-либо дополнительные файлы в том числе **.htaccess** а защитить от прямого доступа при этом надо - как быть?

Или если у меня есть много разных папок доступ к которым нужно закрыть, но при этом мне не удобно в каждую папку класть файл .htaccess, есть ли возможность создать один **.htaccess** в котором будут инструкции запрета сразу к нескольким перечисленным папкам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
RewriteRule ^(includes/|lib/) - [F,L,NC]
```

Запретит доступ к папкам **includes** и **lib**.

Или так:

```
<Files ~ "\includes">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Можно просто редирект для папок сделать на 404 ошибку:

```
Redirect /includes/ 404.html
```